# Generic Dictionary as Parametre

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, dictionary

Can we combine these two methods with the help of IDictionary or something else ?

```
 private static void WriteSourceCredential(XmlWriter pXmlWriter, string key, IDictionary<string, int> resultCountBySources, string value)
    {
        int tempKeyValue;
        pXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("SourceCredentials"); //Start HotelCredential
        pXmlWriter.WriteElementString("Key", key);
        resultCountBySources.TryGetValue(value, out tempKeyValue);
        pXmlWriter.WriteElementString("Value", tempKeyValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // API Key
        pXmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //End HotelCredential
    }

    private static void WriteSourceCredential(XmlWriter pXmlWriter, string key, IDictionary<string, string> sourceCredentials, string value)
    {
        string tempKeyValue;
        pXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("SourceCredentials"); //Start HotelCredential
        pXmlWriter.WriteElementString("Key", key);
        sourceCredentials.TryGetValue(value, out tempKeyValue);
        pXmlWriter.WriteElementString("Value", tempKeyValue); // API Key
        pXmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //End HotelCredential
    }
```

Comment: Maybe changing the parameter type from `IDictionary<string, int>` and `IDictionary<string, string>` to `IDictionary<string, object>` - this way it would accept dictionaries of both kinds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
private static void WriteSourceCredential<TValue>(XmlWriter pXmlWriter, string key, IDictionary<string, TValue> sourceCredentials, string value)
{
    TValue tempKeyValue;
    pXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("SourceCredentials"); //Start HotelCredential
    pXmlWriter.WriteElementString("Key", key);
    sourceCredentials.TryGetValue(value, out tempKeyValue);
    pXmlWriter.WriteElementString("Value", tempKeyValue.ToString()); // API Key
    pXmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); //End HotelCredential
}
```